# Angular NgStyle : list image style

Tags: css, angular

i have an array like this with a name and an image path in my component.

```
 skills = [
    {name: 'HTML5', iconSrc: 'src/assets/images/html-5 min.png'},
    {name: 'CSS3', iconSrc: 'src/assets/images/css-3 min.png'},
    {name: 'UML', iconSrc: 'src/assets/images/hierarchical-structure min.png'},
    {name: 'Javascript', iconSrc: 'src/assets/images/javascript min.png'},
    {name: 'PHP', iconSrc: 'src/assets/images/php min.png'},
    {name: '.NET', iconSrc : 'src/assets/images/hashtag min .png'}
  ];
```

I want to make a loop where i can use the path in iconSrc in the style attribute "list-style-image"
I tried this but it doesn't work

```
<li *ngFor="let skill of skills" [ngStyle]="{'list-style-image': 'url({{skill.iconSrc}})'}">{{skill.name}}</li>
```

Or something like this

```
<li *ngFor="let skill of skills" style="list-style-image: url("{{skill.name}}")">{{skill.name}}</li>
```

What can i do to fix that ?

Comment: You can't use use { or } when using the brackets on the attribute name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you have white space in your images urls so you need to use quotes around the url.
`<li *ngFor="let skill of skills" [ngStyle]="{'list-style-image': 'url(\'' + skill.iconSrc + '\')'}">{{skill.name}}</li>`

Answer (score 2):

You are nearly there! You want a dynamic value in your styles, so it is necessary to use [ngStyle]. style without brackets would not allow any dynamic values. The {{ curly brace syntax }} is only used outside of attribute-values.

This should work:

```
<li *ngFor="let skill of skills" [ngStyle]="{'list-style-image': 'url(\"' + skill.iconSrc + '\")'}">{{skill.name}}</li>
```

Comment: the url will need quotes around it like `url("src/..")`

Comment: Thanks for the explaination. But unfortunately, the list style didn't change. And when i add change the simple quotes for the double, it doesn't compile.

Comment: @TrevorKropp quotes aren't required. OP please update with these changes and the stack trace, "it doesn't compile" isn't helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
[style.listStyleImage]="'url(' + skill.iconSrc + ')'"
```

It's just a different way of achieving what others have posted, but I think it's a pretty clean approach. Make sure your `iconSrc` is correct... I doubt the path you are using will work, probably needs to be `/assets/image.png`